# Yii - CHtml::link() Post with Confirmation Dialog Doesn't work

Tags: php, yii

```
echo CHtml::link('Delete', '#', array('submit'=>'admin/page/exhibitions/delete', 'params'=>array('test'=>50), 'csrf'=>false, 'confirm'=>'Are you sure?' ));
```

I can see in the inspector that Yii has inserted these line of code in html

```
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0',function(){if(confirm('gdfgdfgdfgd')) {jQuery.yii.submitForm(this,'admin/page/exhibitions/delete',{'test':50});return false;} else return false;});
  jQuery('body').on('click','#yt1',function(){if(confirm('gdfgdfgdfgd')) {jQuery.yii.submitForm(this,'admin/page/exhibitions/delete',{'test':50});return false;} else return false;});
  jQuery('body').on('click','#yt2',function(){if(confirm('gdfgdfgdfgd')) {jQuery.yii.submitForm(this,'admin/page/exhibitions/delete',{'test':50});return false;} else return false;});
});
```

However, when I click on the generated link, the confirmation box pop up, when I click ok, nothing happened, except that my console shows the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined`

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: The error occurs because `jquery.yii.js` has not been included in the page. This should have happened automatically. Is there any reference to it in your HTML?

Comment: What is the location of `jquery.yii.js` so that I can include it myself?

Comment: You don't include it yourself, you use [`registerCoreScript('yii')`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCoreScript-detail) to do so. But again, if this does not happen automatically it means there is some unsolved problem in your app.

Answer (score 3):

Check, do you use CForm, CActiveForm, or TBActiveForm widget? Because of submit is an a part of form component and must be wrapped with

```
<form ...></form>
```

and other parameters.

If you want only link - don't use `Submit` parameter.

```
CHtml::link(
    'Delete',
    array('admin/page/exhibitions/delete','test'=>50),
    array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have another jquery at end of the document the jquery.yii.js will be overriden.
Remove another jquery instances.